# Replace the columns in the same order Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, character, multiple-columns, rename

Hi I was removing some characters from the column names in my df but there is a lot of columns with diferent number of characters so I need to remove them specifically for diferent groups so I was using this code for the first 10 columns but it didn't work for the columns 19-29 because are replaced in the firsts columns:

```
new_names = dfr.iloc[:,0:10].rename(columns=lambda x: x[75:]).columns #first 10 columns
dfr.rename(columns=dict(zip(dfr.columns,new_names)),inplace=True)
```

The code that replace the first columns with the second group:

```
new_names = dfr.iloc[:,19:29].rename(columns=lambda x: x[38:]).columns #from  19-29 columns
dfr.rename(columns=dict(zip(dfr.columns,new_names)),inplace=True)
```

So I need to do this like for another 5 more groups some help to finish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
np.random.seed(2020)
  
    
L = ['abdef','trasdfg','ssfgh','dfghj','jhgfdsa','kjhtf','ghrtd']
c = np.random.choice(L, size=10)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, 105, size=(3, 10)), columns=c)
print (df)
   abdef  abdef  dfghj  ghrtd  dfghj  dfghj  kjhtf  dfghj  abdef  kjhtf
0    100    100    100    102    101    103    103    102    103    100
1    104    104    100    104    101    101    102    101    102    104
2    104    102    103    104    101    104    101    103    102    100
```

You can specify how many values are set to new columns names, here `3,4,3` and then in another list specify how many letters are filtered:

```
vals = [3,4,3]
filt=[2,3,1]
```

Then create tuples with cumulative sum and zip for start and end for filter:

```
cols = np.cumsum([0] + vals)

print (list( zip(zip(cols, cols[1:]), filt)))
[((0, 3), 2), ((3, 7), 3), ((7, 10), 1)]
```

In list comprehension create final columns names and set them back:

```
new = [x for (a,b),c in zip(zip(cols, cols[1:]), filt) for x in df.columns[a:b].str[:c]]


df.columns = new
print (df)
    ab   ab   df  ghr  dfg  dfg  kjh    d    a    k
0  100  100  100  102  101  103  103  102  103  100
1  104  104  100  104  101  101  102  101  102  104
2  104  102  103  104  101  104  101  103  102  100
```

Comment: Sorry I was using your code in my df was really long but yeah it was the solution I need it thanks